# Question on Regular Language

Tags: automata

$L= \{a^{2^n} \mid n>1\}  \cup  \{a^m \mid m>1\}$

Is $L$ a regular?

My approach is-- union of a non regular and regular language may be regular or may be not regular.
The left side of union is not regular so the language L is not regular.

Please advise.

Comment: The first set is a subset of the second one, isn't it? Why does this help you?

Comment: so we can write the union as L={$a^m$,m>1}?  can we say L is regular.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I leave it to you to decide if $\{a^m \mid m>1\} $ is regular or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help.The language L is regular,since we can draw a DFA for this.

Comment: Your approach is bogus: you say that the union may be regular or not, then you immediately conclude that it is not. What's the logics ?

Comment: Hi Yves, I am trying to learn the concepts.Please advise which approach shall I try.